# Laravel 5.6 update foreign key in database after storing resource

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a resource 'imagerequest' and a resource 'events'. For each of these resources I have a Modal and the relationship is as following:

1 Imagerequest can have many Events:

Imagerequest model:

```
/**
 * Get the events for an Image Request.
 */
public function events()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Event');
}
```

Event model:

```
/**
 * Get the Image Request that belongs to the Event
 */
public function imagerequest()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\ImageRequest');
}
```

Now in my form when creating a new Imagerequest I have an other form to create multiple events but my problem is when I store a new Event there is no image_request_id because the new image_request_id doesn't exist yet since I haven't created the imagerequest yet.

So in my database image_request_id is always empty

```
id user_id image_request_id location trainnr created_at  updated_at
1  53      NULL             location NULL    2019-05-28  10:49:45 2019-05-28 10:49:45
```

Do I need to write an update query after saving the imagerequest to fill up this image_request_id?

How I create a new Event in my EventController:

```
$event = Auth::user()->events()->save(new Event($request->all()));
```

How I create a new Imagerequest in my ImagerequestController:

```
$imageRequest = new ImageRequest(
    array_merge(
        $request->all(),
        ['status' => self::STATUS_NEW]
    )
);

$imageRequest = Auth::user()->imageRequests()->save($imageRequest);
```

### EDIT my front end for adding an event

[image]

Comment: How are you creating an image_request? Can you add the code to your question.

Comment: @kmgkumar I don't think you understand the problem, the problem is when creating a new Event I don't have an image_request_id because I haven't stored the new Imagerequest yet because I have a form form my Events in the form for creating my Imagerequest

Comment: I think the structure of your application is the problem. Is it not possible to send the image_request and event data in a single request and handle them in a single controller?

Comment: @Jeemusu no since it's 2 seperate resources and should be treated like this

Comment: 1 imagerequest can have multiple events

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding how the flow of your application works. Could you explain a bit more in detail the process of adding an image_request, and then events.

Comment: @Jeemusu let's say you're requesting images of a man during a weekend holiday the man may have been spotted in city x and city y now city x and city y are 2 "events" that the requester adds so the people who are gonna look for these images now where to look

Comment: In that case I would suggest you send them as a single request and handle it in a single controller method as @josh has suggest in his answer below.

Comment: @Jeemusu I don't understand this how can I add multiple events than? I need to create multiple inputs with the same name?

Comment: @micheal This is a very simplified version but you could do something like this. https://jsfiddle.net/ujo6rs48/1/. By adding `[]` to the name of an input all inputs with the same name will be submited as an array. So if you input `city A` in one input, added a new one and input `city B`, then access the event variable from the request it should contain `['city A', 'city B']`.

Comment: But an event is either a location or a number so I need 2 input fields for every event if the one is filled in the other should be grayed out and an event has more fields I'll update original post

Comment: Yes, the example was heavily simplified. You should be able to work out how to add another input. If javascript is not your forte I would suggest instead handling it as two requests (multistep form). Have the user submit the image_request details first, save them in the DB then redirect them to a new page and add the $id of the image_request into a hidden input in the form and have them submit the events.

Comment: @Jeemusu I edit my original post check it out if you want I'll try to get the front end working and then I'll come back to Josh's solution to try to get the back end working

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the relationship

[have a look at the docs for more help with this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models)

From my quick look you can do it something like this:

```
$event = Auth::user()->events()->save(new Event($request->all()));

$imageRequest = new ImageRequest(
    array_merge(
        $request->all(),
        ['status' => self::STATUS_NEW]
    )
);

$event->imagerequest()->create($imageRequest);
```

I would also advise that you validate any request data before you update the database also.

**EDIT base on more info**

you can do something like this then:

```
$imageRequest->attach($request->eventIds);
```

Comment: I know I can do this but the creation of the Event and Imagerequest happens in 2 different controllers on 2 different form submits

Comment: How can I create multiple events then? I need to create multiple inputs beforehand? then there can be empty ones also

Comment: I think your front end flow is the problem. If this were me, I would have a single form where a user can add all the image_request details, and then some javascript that allows the user to append/remove events to this form. Then send it all in a single request to the image_request controller. Otherwise maybe you could have the user create the image_request first,  store the image_request id in the session then afterwards have them add the events on a seperate request?

Comment: Have a look at my edit. Thar should help you with the solution

Comment: @Jeemusu that is exactly how my front end looks like I just don't know how I can attach multiple events and send it as 1 request that my input fields need to have all the same name?